# Qt Creator indentation changes at save

Tags: qt, coding-style, ide, qt-creator, indentation

I'm using Qt Creator and I'm willing to create my own coding style.

The only thing I changed in the default Qt [built-in] settings is changed "Tab policy" to "Tabs Only" and "Align continuation lines" to "With regular indent". "Tab size" and "Indent size" are both set to 4.

And I get the following indentation:

```
int function( int param1 )
{
<  t  >if(  param != 0 &&
<  t  >< s >param != 1 )
<  t  >{
<  t  ><  t  >//do something
<  t  >}
}
```

< t > is for tabs and < s > is for spaces.

The problem is that when I save (Ctrl+S) Qt Creator converts spaces into tabs. How can I set it not to convert anything and not change the indentation when saving?

Comment: Even worse when editing a makefile it removes all tabs from the entire file on save. Almost comical as it's impossible to workaround.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look here:

```
Tools > Options > Text Editor > Behavior
cleanups upon saving section
```

Or if you want for current project only (change qt creator version in path)

http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-editor-settings.html

Answer (score 1):

You can the details below for:

- Text files
- C++ files
- QML files

http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-indenting-code.html