# How to Convert Tabs into Whitespaces on Save?

Tags: visual-studio-code, tabs, whitespace, indentation

I want to change tabs to whitespaces when I save the file.
I thought there would an option in the settings or at least an extension, but I was not able to see it.

I have seen many other posts for removing `trim.trailingWhitespace`, but that is not what I am looking for.
I am also using the conversion from tabs to whitespaces when pressing the Tab key. But that is, again, not my issue.

What I am looking for is to save the file and automatically change all the tabs to whitespaces, like Qt Creator does.

Comment: How to make QtCretor "automatically change all the tabs to whitespaces" on save?

Comment: As mentioned in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387920/qt-creator-indentation-changes-at-save


Official Documentation:
https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-editor-settings.html

Answer (score 6):

It is going to depend on the language. You need to install/setup a language-specific formatter and then enable the `"editor.formatOnSave"` setting, which will literally apply the formatter rules when saving files.

This answer is for Python and JavaScript because that's what I normally use.

---

For JavaScript, I use the [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) extension.
(It has [plugins for other languages](https://prettier.io/docs/en/plugins.html) but I've mainly used it for JS.)

Then add these to your *settings.json*:

```
// Set the default setting
"editor.formatOnSave": false,

// Then toggle depending on the language
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
},
```

By default, Prettier already provides some default formatting rules. But you can specify your [own configuration file](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html) to specify your own (or a project-specific) set of formatting rules.

```
.
├── ...
├── .prettierrc.js
├── test.js
...
└── <<other files>>
```

In *.prettierrc.js*:

```js
// prettier.config.js or .prettierrc.js
module.exports = {
    useTabs: false,
    tabWidth: 4
};
```

That Prettier config specifies not to use tabs and use an indentation level of 4 spaces. Now, with that setup, when you save a file, it will automatically change tabs to whitespaces (which is what I understand is what you want). There are also [other formatting options](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html).

You'll know the extension is working because it shows "Prettier" in the status bar:

[image]

---

For Python, [VS Code currently supports 3 formatting providers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatting)):

- "autopep8"
- "yapf"
- "black".

I use "autopep8".

Install `autopep8` on your environment. Then in VS Code, make sure to [select the environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) that has `autopep8`. Then add this to your settings.json:

```
// Set the default setting
"editor.formatOnSave": false,

"[python]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
},

"python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
"python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
    // "--ignore=W191, E101, E111"  // Uncomment to disable fixing indentation
],
```

Here, [autopep8](https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/#features) formats code to follow the [PEP8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces), which already recommends [spaces over tabs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces). So all that needs to be done is enable it.

---

You might also be interested in VS Code settings related to spaces (so that tabs will not be put into the file in the first place):

```
"editor.detectIndentation": false,
"editor.insertSpaces": true,
"editor.tabSize": 4,
```

Comment: Thank you Gino, but it did not work :S 

Steps I followed: 
1. Download Prettier - Code formatter
2. Change Default Formatter in VS Code settings to esbenp.prettier-vscode
3. Set `"editor.formatOnSave": true` for all languages (just don't specify the language)
4. Create a new file called .prettierConfig.js
5. Add the following to the settings.json:
    `"prettier.configPath": ".prettierConfig.js",
    "prettier.tabWidth": 4,
    "prettier.useEditorConfig": false`

Comment: It seems to work on .vscode/settings.json, but not on ~/.config/Code/User/settings.json

Comment: I am trying to do it for all languages. It shouldn't matter which language it is.

Comment: @Kikadass "*but it did not work*" : Well, it's because the steps you did is quite *different* from what I described in my answer. I tried my steps again on a different machine, and it works. I updated my answer to specify Prettier for JS and autopep8 for Python, as both have different steps/settings to use.

Comment: @Kikadass "*It seems to work on .vscode/settings.json, but not on ~/.config/Code/User/settings.json*" VS Code has separate settings for User (*Code/User/settings.json*)  and Workspace (*.vscode/settings.json*). (See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings). Make sure you don't have conflicting settings in Workspace, as those override the ones in User.

Comment: @Kikadass "*I am trying to do it for all languages.*" I don't think you can, as *different* languages have *different* formatting, and *different formatters* that can properly fix the code to apply those *different* formats. You'll have to find a formatter that can handle *all* the languages you are going to use. You can try setting `"editor.formatOnSave": true` but that just tells VS Code to ["*pick up relevant installed formatter extensions*"](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_6#_format-on-save), which falls back to my answer of installing language-specific formatters.

Comment: Sorry, I should specify that I tried your way and many others, and none seemed to work.
I also had the same config in both the Workspace and the User, which made no difference.
I am trying to do it for all languages, as I work with many different ones at the same time, and the tabs to spaces change on save should not be a specific thing for a language, but for all, such as in QT Creator.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I face an indentation problem, I go online and google "beautify python code" and the 2nd or 3rd link of tutorials-point helps me out( [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_python_formatter.htm) ).
Just put in your code and it will (in most cases) completely fix it for you or guide you theough the errors in a better way than an interpreter.